# C program not executing: permission denied

Tags: c

I have installed C/C++ compiler using

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

created file named "first.c" and write an initial code of C language in it.

```
cc -c first.c

cc -o first first.c

./first

-bash: ./first: Permission denied

chmod +x first

ls -al


sana@ubuntu:/media/E68828DA8828AACF/Documents/cWork$ ls -al
total 25
drwx------ 1 sana sana 4096 Dec 16 08:47 .
drwx------ 1 sana sana 4096 Dec 16 08:17 ..
-rw------- 1 sana sana 8379 Dec 16 08:47 first
-rw------- 1 sana sana   82 Dec 16 08:23 first.c
-rw------- 1 sana sana   82 Dec 16 08:22 first.c~
-rw------- 1 sana sana 1504 Dec 16 08:23 first.o
```

Solved : using changing my current working directory to **sana@ubuntu:~/Documents$** instead **sana@ubuntu:/media/E68828DA8828AACF/Documents/cWork$**

why ?? i dont understand

```
     sana@ubuntu:~/Documents$ touch first.c
     sana@ubuntu:~/Documents$ gedit first.c
     sana@ubuntu:~/Documents$ cc -c first.c
     sana@ubuntu:~/Documents$ cc -o first first.c
     sana@ubuntu:~/Documents$ ./first
     i am sana 
     sana@ubuntu:~/Documents$
```

**yes exacty the device is mounted with noexec option that do not execute any script from drive to run scripts you need to change noexec option. The method of which is given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246320/how-to-mount-disc-with-exec-permissions) .**

Comment: `chmod +x first` ? Files are not executable by default.

Comment: Try using `gcc` instead?

Comment: That's odd; normally, the C compiler will make the program executable by default (when you create a binary, as you did).  What's the setting of your `umask`?  If it includes a 1 bit for user, modify it so that it doesn't: `umask 022` or `umask 027` are usually reasonable options.

Comment: chmod +x first did not work for me

Comment: OK: if `chmod +x first` does not work, then you probably have some sort of cross-compilation problem.  What does `file ./first /bin/sh` say?  Does it say the same thing about the two executables? Is one 64-bit and the other 32-bit? Is your system capable of running 64-bit code?  You might also run `ldd first` to see whether all the relevant shared libraries are available, but I wouldn't expect a 'permission denied' message ('no such file or directory' would be more like what I'd expect).

Comment: Not relevant to the permission problem, but the first `cc` is producing a `first.o` which doesn't get used because the second `cc` is given `first.c` directly.

Comment: **ldd first**
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd6b27000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0115b36000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0115f12000)

Comment: `build-essentioal`.  Where's this typo coming from?

Comment: typo error @Bit Fiddling Code Monkey

Comment: @samRobort I'm embarrassed.  Thanks for making it public. ;-)

Comment: no mention @Bit Fiddling Code Monkey

Comment: `/media/E68828DA8828AACF/` strange home. Are you sure the device is mounted read/write?

Comment: Were any errors or warnings output when you typed `cc -o first first.c`?

Comment: @Mark Plotnick: good point. I suggest actually also running cc -Wall -o first first.c, and share any warnings you might see with SO.

Comment: Solved : using changing my current working directory to sana@ubuntu:~/Documents$ instead sana@ubuntu:/media/E68828DA8828AACF/Documents/cWork$ y??

Comment: Interesting. Is `/media/E68828DA8828AACF` a FAT-formatted thumb drive? Maybe the mount options forbid creating executables on it.

Comment: Is the directory your code is in mounted with the `noexec` option?

Comment: in actual my ubuntu is running in one of the partition of windows 8 and this is the partition where i did **not** install ubuntu but i want to keep all my code in that partition both in ubuntu and windows.

Comment: yes exacty the device is mounted with noexec option that do not execute any script prom drive to run scripts you need to change noexec option. The method of which is given [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/246320/how-to-mount-disc-with-exec-permissions) .

Answer (score 1):

Did you give execute permission to `first`; done by `chmod +x first`?

Comment: Well, yes, but the real question is "Why didn't the compiler give the executable execute permissions?", because I've not seen a system where the output from the linker when creating a binary was not automatically executable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've also seen cases where a 32-bit binary wasn't recognized as executable on a 64-bit OS (Linux) because there weren't 32 bit runtime libraries installed.

Comment: @H2CO3: given that `chmod +x` did not help, there must be some such problem — the binary is not supported on the runtime.

Comment: @samRobort Can you do `ls -al` and ensure that you have got the permissions right?

Comment: sana@ubuntu:/media/E68828DA8828AACF/Documents/cWork$ **ls -al**
total 25
drwx------ 1 sana sana 4096 Dec 16 08:47 .
drwx------ 1 sana sana 4096 Dec 16 08:17 ..
-rw------- 1 sana sana 8379 Dec 16 08:47 first
-rw------- 1 sana sana   82 Dec 16 08:23 first.c
-rw------- 1 sana sana   82 Dec 16 08:22 first.c~
-rw------- 1 sana sana 1504 Dec 16 08:23 first.o

Comment: ..but permissions on first seem to be -rw-------

Comment: I wish you had formatted it well.  Please try `cc first.c` followed by `chmod +x first`

Comment: yes i also do **chmod +x first++ then y permissions not changed

Comment: @samRobort: The syntax is chmod u+x first (if I'm not unfamiliar with some default where '+x' is enough). Based on your ls -al, first is still not executable. Try this command, to at least see if you can change permission? (ls -la again after and check if you see rwx for first). If not, try sudo chmod u+x first and see if it makes a difference. This shouldn't be necessary for cc, but your problem is puzzling, so try to narrow it down.

Comment: Solved : using changing my current working directory to sana@ubuntu:~/Documents$ instead sana@ubuntu:/media/E68828DA8828AACF/Documents/cWork$

Comment: @PhantomReference: `cc first.c` will create `a.out`, not `first`.